# Klein-Gordon equations in quintessence

Tags: cosmology, differential-geometry, differential-equations, dark-energy

I'm studying the quintessence model from a dynamical system point of view. I denoted the scalar field for the dark energy as $\phi$, so I have the following Klein-Gordon equation for the field $$\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu \phi-\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}=0.$$ Considering a homogeneous, isotropic, spatially flat FLRW metric $$ds^2=-dt^2+a(t)^2(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2),$$ the equation takes the simple form $$\phi''+3H\phi'+\frac{\partial V}{\partial\phi},$$ where $H=a'/a$ and $V$ is the potential of the field. I'm a pure mathematician so many of these things are unknown for me at their deepest, so I don't really know how one gets from the KG equation to the simple form. Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I know only a pretty lengthy way to go there, let me just sketch here the elements of the proof. First consider the so-called continuity equation, which states that the energy-momentum is conserved locally in a curved space-time. It is at the basis of GR (you can derive it by taking the covariant derivative of Einstein's equations) and is written as

$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0 $$

Now, the symmetries of the FLRW metric forces all the entities within it to be "ideal fluids", with stress-energy tensor of the form $${\rm diag}(-\rho,p,p,p)$$, where $\rho$ is the energy density of the field and $p$ is the pressure. This form is imposed by the symmetries you ask to space when doing cosmology: homogeneity and isotropy.

Now, considering the component $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu}_{\,0}$ of this equation in a FLRW metric, you will be able to derive

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + 3H(p+\rho)=0$$

You can find further explanations and details of this derivation in any standard textbook of cosmology (feel free to ask if you need some references).

Now, your scalar field will be described by a Lagrangian of the form $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\partial^\mu \phi - V$.

With a general metric, this Lagrangian will give you the equation you mentionned above ($\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu\phi-\partial_\phi V=0$) through Euler-Lagrange minimization.

From this Lagrangian you can derive the stress-energy tensor of $\phi$, as usually done in field theory, still within the assumption of perfect fluid : homogeneity and isotropy (You also ask for the spatial derivatives will then vanish, as the field has to be homogeneous in space).

You will get

$$ p=\frac{\phi'^2}{2}-V$$ and $$\rho = \frac{\phi'^2}{2}+V$$.

Now putting that back in the continuity equation above, you will get the Klein-Gordon equation asked above.

$$ \phi'' + 3H\phi' = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}$$

Perhaps there is a more direct way to find this equation from the Lagrangian through Euler-Lagrange minimization in curved space-time.

Comment: Thanks! I think i understand it, do you know any reference where this could be find in detail?

Comment: Sure ! Have a look at "Primordial Cosmology" from Peter & Uzan Chapter 1.3.2.4 or Dodelson's "modern cosmology" ., chapter 7.2. Let me know if you find other interesting approaches more mathematically oriented ;)